# ploting after "assign" function in R

Tags: r, data-visualization, dataset

My task is to create 5 plots (age versus height) for each tree, broken down by habitat
type.

Here is my code:

```
par(mfrow = c(3,2))
data_x <- split(treeg,treeg$habitat)
new_names <- c('one','two','three','four','five')
for(i in 1:length(data_x)){
    assign(paste(new_names[i]),data_x[[i]])
}
```

Here i have splited my data frame "treeg"(that consists of 5 variables:ID,forest,habitat,dbh.in,height.ft,age) by "habitat". Then i have created 5 separeted data_frames with names 'one','two',...etc

So i have two questions:
1) How can i get access to the new data frames, that i have created? I mean, to get access with a purpose of plotting:

```
for(i in 1:length(data_x)){
    assign(paste(new_names[i]),data_x[[i]])
    plot(created_dataframe$height.ft,created_dataframe$age,type = 'l')
```

2)Is there more effective way of doing my problem?

P.S The data set
treeg <- read.csv("http://www.ms.unimelb.edu.au/~odj/Teaching/MAST30025/data/treegrowth.csv")

Answer (score 0):

When you have a variable name stored as character, you can use `get()` to get the contents of the variable. So, your code could be changed to the following in order to create the plots:

```
treeg <- read.table("Downloads/treegrowth.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")
par(mfrow = c(3,2), mar = c(4.2, 4.2, 1, 1))
data_x <- split(treeg,treeg$habitat)
new_names <- c('one','two','three','four','five')

for(i in 1:length(data_x)){
  assign(new_names[i],data_x[[i]])
  created_dataframe <- get(new_names[i])
  plot(created_dataframe$height.ft, created_dataframe$age, type = 'l')
}
```

I have added the parameter `mar` to `par()`, because the default margins are quite large and the plots turn out very small. Your use of `paste()` was unnecessary and I removed it. Using `get()` the data frame is stored in `created_dataframe` and used in the plot command below.

However, this is not the best way to do this. There is actually no need to store the data frames under new names. It is much more convenient to just keep the data frames in the list (`data_x`), because this allows you to access them by index and you need neither `assign()` nor `get()`. So this will also produce the plot:

```
treeg <- read.table("Downloads/treegrowth.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")
par(mfrow = c(3,2), mar = c(4.2, 4.2, 1, 1))
data_x <- split(treeg,treeg$habitat)

for(i in 1:length(data_x)){
  plot(data_x[[i]]$height.ft, data_x[[i]]$age, type = 'l')
}
```

If you want, you can also replace the `for`-loop by `lapply()`:

```
lapply(data_x, function(x) plot(x$height.ft, x$age, type = 'l'))
```

This is the plot:

[image]